# VBA: Named Argument Not Found, Multiple .Finds

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to get VBA to search a column of cells (that will be user-populated) to find specific criteria. After struggling with WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(, I've settled on this code, and up to this point, it seemed to work:

```
Sub CalendarColor()

Call VarDef

Dim SearchEmpList As Range
Dim SearchSDate As Range
Dim SearchEDate As Range
Dim SearchLType As Range
Dim SearchPType As Range

If EmpName <> "" Then
    With Worksheets(2).Range("B:B") 'Search all of Employee Name list entries
        Set SearchEmpList = .Find(What:=EmpName, _
                                  After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                  MatchCase:=False)
    End With
```

So that is the first column and the first variable that has to be identified. To move on to the relevant start date, I added this code:

```
    With Worksheets(2).Range("C:C") 'Search all of Start Date list entries
        Set SearchSDate = .Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SeachOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SeachDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
    End With
```

To my eye, this is exactly the same, but I'm getting the "Run-time error '448': Named argument not found" when using step-into to debug.

Is it the ActiveCell.Value? If so, what else can I use? This script is going to be used in a loop script, which offsets by 1 each iteration -- so ActiveCell seems the most plausible if it works at all.

Loop script looks like this:

```
Sub ColorLoop()

Dim EndNumberA As Integer '31 day months
Dim EndNumberB As Integer '30 day months
Dim EndnumberC As Integer '28 day months
Dim EndNumberD As Integer '29 day months
Dim i As Integer

EndNumberA = 31
EndNumberB = 30
EndnumberC = 28
EndNumberD = 29

'Offset commands need to be tweaked each year to ensure the ActiveCell lands on the first day of the next month

'January 31d
For i = 1 To EndNumberA
    Call CalendarColor
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Select
Next i

'Set ActiveCell to Feb1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -28).Select

'February 28d (Use EndNumberD if leap year)
For i = 1 To EndnumberC
    'Call CalendarColor
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Select
Next i

'Set ActiveCell to Mar1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -28).Select
```

I am about 2 weeks into learning VBA (and my first post here), so whatever you have is welcome information.

Comment: `SeachOrder` <> `SearchOrder`, `SeachDirection` <> `SearchDirection`.

Comment: I am not sure what this means...? Sorry!

Comment: you are missing **r** in seachOrder

Comment: Well. That's embarrassing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeachOrder:=xlByRows, _
SeachDirection:=xlNext, _
```

Those are typos.  Search not Seach!